# How do you express a single equation as a system of equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

I have the equation $(2x-3)(ax+b)+(x^2-2)(cx+d) = 1$, and somehow I have to arrive at the following system:

$c = 0$ 
$2a+d = 0$ 
$2b-3a-2c = 0$ 
$-3b - 2d = 1$

I'm completely blanking on the math necessary.

Comment: The "single" equation holds true for all values of $x$, so it's really as many equations as you want - just give different values to $x$.

Comment: The equations represent the coefficients of the polynomials (in $x$) of both sides. For example, the second equation says there are $2a+d$ $x^2$ terms on the LHS and $0$ $x^2$ terms on the RHS. These coefficients must be identical, which allows you to solve for $a,b,c,d$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply everything out and collect terms to $Ax^3 + Bx^2 + Cx + D = 1$, and then compare coefficients to find A, B, C, and D.

Comment: To add to this answer, it might be more transparent if one were to write the RHS as $1=0x^3+0x^2+0x+1$.